# See current cost (live)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to see the current hourly / daily cost of the currently running infrastructure in GCP?

Some hours ago I started a kubernetes cluster (actually using the free 300$ start credit) and I am wondering how long this will last and how much I have to pay once it is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an overview of your costs on a per-project basis in the Reports section of the Billing interface, both by hour and by day.

Since GKE uses Compute Engine instances, [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) you should be able to use the Compute Engine [Usage Reports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) to for detailed daily spending information.

To get an estimate of your Kubernetes costs alone you can use the [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).